# Difference between Scrapy selectors "a::text" and "a ::text"

Tags: python, python-3.x, css-selectors, scrapy, pseudo-element

I've created a scraper to grab some product names from a webpage. It is working smoothly. I've used CSS selectors to do the job. However, the only thing I can't understand is the difference between the selectors `a::text` and `a ::text` (don't overlook the space between `a` and `::text` in the latter). When I run my script, I get the same exact result no matter which selector I choose.

```
import requests
from scrapy import Selector

res = requests.get("https://www.kipling.com/uk-en/sale/type/all-sale/?limit=all#")
sel = Selector(res)
for item in sel.css(".product-list-product-wrapper"):
    title = item.css(".product-name a::text").extract_first().strip()
    title_ano = item.css(".product-name a ::text").extract_first().strip()
    print("Name: {}\nName_ano: {}\n".format(title,title_ano))
```

As you can see, both `title` and `title_ano` contain the same selector, bar the space in the latter. Nevertheless, the results are always the same.

My question: is there any substantial difference between the two, and when should I use the former and when the latter?

Comment: How are these "use cases"? Are you simply asking about CSS syntax?

Comment: No, answers are what we post down in the big box below with the "Post Your Answer" button. What I posted is a comment. It doesn't contain any attempt at answering, it's asking you to clarify your question -- ideally, [edit] it to have a better title, better problem description, and suitable tags.

Comment: Which portion of my description is unclear? Which tags I've chosen I didn't use in my scraper? Gonna edit the title though.

Comment: @novice-coder , can you share any reference to `::text` pseudo-element? I can't find anything about its existence...

Comment: Thanks sir Andersson, for your comment. Basically, when I parse any text out of some elements using css selectors, I don't need that usage `::text`, be it `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` library. However, when it comes to parse the same using scrapy then this is mandatory `::text` to get the text. You know that very well. The point is: I didn't find much difference using space in between to parse any text from some elements but there should be any `do's and don'ts` about the usage. That is what I wish to know.

Comment: @novice-coder, I don't use Scrapy, so actually I don't know how to get text from node with `::text` :) I just never heard about this pseudo-element. IMHO I don't really think that space could ever make any difference in your case... Also I don't think that this question deserves downvotes :)

Comment: @tripleee: Title aside, in what way is the problem description unclear (are a ::text and a::text functionally equivalent, if not, how are they different and what are the, ahem, *use cases* for each) or the tags not suitable (question is about the selectors used by Python web scraping library called Scrapy)?

Comment: With the title fixed and the clarifications here in the comments, I don't think this is unclear any longer, and I have retracted my vote to close as unclear. Thanks for the ping.

Comment: @tripleee: No worries. I ended up putting an unexpected amount of time and research into answering this question, so I thought I'd refine the question some more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interesting observation! I spent the past couple of hours investigating this and it turns out, there's a lot more to it than meets the eye.

If you're coming from CSS, you'd probably expect to write `a::text` in much the same way you'd write `a::first-line`, `a::first-letter`, `a::before` or `a::after`. No surprises there.

On the other hand, standard selector syntax would suggest that `a ::text` matches the `::text` pseudo-element of a *descendant* of the `a` element, making it equivalent to `a *::text`. However, `.product-list-product-wrapper .product-name a` doesn't have any child elements, so by rights, `a ::text` is supposed to match nothing. The fact that it does match suggests that Scrapy is not following the grammar.

Scrapy uses Parsel (itself based on cssselect) to translate selectors into XPath, which is where `::text` comes from. With that in mind, let's examine how Parsel implements `::text`:

```
>>> from parsel import css2xpath
>>> css2xpath('a::text')
'descendant-or-self::a/text()'
>>> css2xpath('a ::text')
'descendant-or-self::a/descendant-or-self::text()'
```

So, like cssselect, anything that follows a descendant combinator is translated into a `descendant-or-self` axis, but because text nodes are proper children of element nodes in the DOM, `::text` is treated as a standalone node and converted directly to `text()`, which, with the `descendant-or-self` axis, matches any text node that is a descendant of an `a` element, just as `a/text()` matches any text node *child* of an `a` element (a child is also a descendant).

Egregiously, this happens even when you add an explicit `*` to the selector:

```
>>> css2xpath('a *::text')
'descendant-or-self::a/descendant-or-self::text()'
```

However, the use of the `descendant-or-self` axis means that `a ::text` can match all text nodes in the `a` element, including those in other elements nested within the `a`. In the following example, `a ::text` will match two text nodes: `'Link '` followed by `'text'`:

```html
<a href="https://example.com">Link <span>text</span></a>
```

So while Scrapy's implementation of `::text` is an egregious violation of the Selectors grammar, it seems to have been done this way very much intentionally.

In fact, Scrapy's other pseudo-element `::attr()`<sup>1</sup> behaves similarly. The following selectors all match the `id` attribute node belonging to the `div` element when it does not have any descendant elements:

```
>>> css2xpath('div::attr(id)')
'descendant-or-self::div/@id'
>>> css2xpath('div ::attr(id)')
'descendant-or-self::div/descendant-or-self::*/@id'
>>> css2xpath('div *::attr(id)')
'descendant-or-self::div/descendant-or-self::*/@id'
```

... but `div ::attr(id)` and `div *::attr(id)` will match all `id` attribute nodes within the `div`'s descendants along with its own `id` attribute, such as in the following example:

```html
<div id="parent"><p id="child"></p></div>
```

This, of course, is a much less plausible use case, so one has to wonder if this was an unintentional side effect of the implementation of `::text`.

Compare the pseudo-element selectors to one that substitutes any simple selector for the pseudo-element:

```
>>> css2xpath('a [href]')
'descendant-or-self::a/descendant-or-self::*/*[@href]'
```

This correctly translates the descendant combinator to `descendant-or-self::*/*` with an additional implicit `child` axis, ensuring that the `[@href]` predicate is never tested on the `a` element.

If you're new to XPath, Selectors, or even Scrapy, this may all seem very confusing and overwhelming. So here's a summary of when to use one selector over the other:

- Use `a::text` if your `a` element contains only text, or if you're only interested in the top-level text nodes of this `a` element and not its nested elements.
- Use `a ::text` if your `a` element contains nested elements and you want to extract all the text nodes within this `a` element.

  While you *can* use `a ::text` if your `a` element contains only text, its syntax is confusing, so for the sake of consistency, use `a::text` instead.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>On an interesting note, `::attr()` appears in the (abandoned as of 2021) [Non-element Selectors spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-nonelement/#attribute-node-selectors), where as you'd expect it behaves consistently with the Selectors grammar, making its behavior in Scrapy inconsistent with the spec. `::text` on the other hand is conspicuously missing from the spec; based on this answer, I think you can make a reasonable guess as to why.</sub>